# Plugin to create Posts and Forums then choose category and parent forum

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, wp-insert-post, bbpress

I need to create a plugin for a customer that will help him create posts and forums and place them in a category and choose if it's a parent or a child forum.

**Just created a GitHub Repo for my files : https://github.com/maisdesign/MDPostEforumsCreator**

My current installation is : **WordPress + BBPress + BuddyPress**.

This is how I would like it to work:

[image: It creates Articles and Forum with same name]

As you can see there is a simple form where user will have to write the Title of a post and choose a category.

After clicking on submit the plugin will create a post with that title and also a forum with that title.

This is my code that, after some help by @s_ha_dum(thank you), now partially works.

Next step would be to add the possibility to choose a parent forum so the just created forum would be parent or child.

I can't find any documentation about this BBPress function.

Is there any equivalent of *wp_dropdown_categories* but for BBPress?

Is there anyone who can help me?

**File index.php**

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Post And Forum Creator by MaisDesign & Stestaz
Plugin URI: http://maisdesign.it
Description: You give it a title and it automatically create a blank post and forum with that title, that's it!
Version: 1.0.0
Author: MaisDesign & Stestaz
Author URI: http://maisdesign.it
License: 
License URI: 
*/
/* Documentazione:
    Quello che sto cercando di ottenere è di svolgere tutto in una sola pagina, sono certo che non serva richiamare BBHOST e compagnia bella per inserire un cavolo di articolo ma sono le 2.20 AM e non so più che pesci pigliare!
    In fondo a questa pagina troverai del codice commentato, se ci sono bestemmie nei commenti lasciale dove stanno, sono di buon auspicio :-P
*/
/* Definiamo la versione */

if (!defined('MD_POSTFORUM_CREATOR_VERSION_KEY'))
    define('MD_POSTFORUM_CREATOR_VERSION_KEY', 'md_postforum_creator_version');

if (!defined('MD_POSTFORUM_CREATOR_VERSION_NUM'))
    define('MD_POSTFORUM_CREATOR_VERSION_NUM', '1.0.0');

add_option(MD_POSTFORUM_CREATOR_VERSION_KEY, MD_POSTFORUM_CREATOR_VERSION_NUM);

/*
    * This example will work at least on WordPress 2.6.3, 
    * but maybe on older versions too.
    */
   add_action( 'admin_init', 'md_postforum_creator_init' );
   add_action( 'admin_menu', 'md_postforum_creator_menu' );

   function md_postforum_creator_init() {
       /* Register our stylesheet. */
       wp_register_style( 'mdPostforumCreatorStyle', plugins_url('css/mdpostforumstyle.css', __FILE__) );
           wp_register_script( 'mdPostforumCreatorScript', plugins_url( '/js/alajax-1.2.js', __FILE__ ) );
   };   
   function md_postforum_creator_menu() {
       /* Register our plugin page */
       $page = add_submenu_page( 'options.php', 
                                 __( 'MDPFC Plugin', 'md-postforum-creator' ), 
                                 __( 'MDPFC Plugin', 'md-postforum-creator' ),
                                 'administrator',
                                 __FILE__, 
                                 'md_postforum_creator_manage_menu' );

       /* Using registered $page handle to hook stylesheet loading */
       add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $page, 'md_postforum_creator_styles' );
        add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page, 'md_postforum_creator_scripts');
   };   
   function md_postforum_creator_styles() {
       /*
        * It will be called only on your plugin admin page, enqueue our stylesheet here
        */
       wp_enqueue_style( 'mdPostforumCreatorStyle' );
   };
   function md_postforum_creator_scripts() {
        /* Link our already registered script to a page */
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mdPostforumCreatorScript' );
    };
   /*function md_postforum_creator_manage_menu() {
   };*/
   add_action('admin_menu', 'register_md_postforum_creator_menu');
function register_md_postforum_creator_menu() {
   add_menu_page( 'MDPFC Options', // $page_title
                  'MDPFC Options', // $menu_title
                  'manage_options', // $capability
                  'md-postforum-creator-menu-page-slug', // $menu_slug
                  'md_postforum_creator_menu_page', // $function
                  plugins_url( 'md-postforum-creator/images/mdpostforum.png' ), /* $icon_url*/
                  3 ); /* $position*/
};

function md_postforum_creator_menu_page() {
   /* Does the user have the right permissions?*/
   if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
      wp_die( 'Sorry, you do not have permission to access this page.');
   };
  if(isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') {
    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
    $post_category = $_POST['cat'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

    $new_post = array(
          'ID' => '',
          'post_author' => $user->ID, 
          'post_category' => array($post_category),
          'post_content' => '', 
          'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($post_title),
          'post_status' => 'draft'
        );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    if (is_plugin_active('bbpress/bbpress.php')) {
    $forum_id = bbp_insert_forum( array(
                /*'post_parent'  => bbp_get_group_forums_root_id(),*/
                'post_title'   => $post_title,
                /*'post_content' => $group->description,*/
                'post_status'  => 'draft'
            ) );
    /*$default_forum = array(   
        $_POST['post_title']     => array($post_category),
    );


    $forum = bbp_insert_forum( $default_forum );*/
    };
};          
echo '
<form action="'.admin_url('admin.php?page=md-postforum-creator-menu-page-slug').'" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/>';

    wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&hierarchical=1');

    echo '<input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>';
};?>
```

Comment: _Exactly_ what doesn't work? Where _precisely_ does the code fail? Can you narrow this down?

Comment: If I click on submit... no post is added :-)

Answer (score 1):

If that is the complete code for `ste.php` then you are loading it without any WordPress context, which means that functions like `wp_insert_post` are not going to be defined. If you check your server logs you will probably see errors to that effect.

The easy, and I'd argue the best, solution to this is to process your form on the same page you use to submit it. That page is registered as a WordPress menu page so WordPress Core is loaded.

```
function md_postforum_creator_menu_page() {
   /* Does the user have the right permissions?*/
   if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
      wp_die( 'Sorry, you do not have permission to access this page.');
   };
   if (!empty($_POST)) {
     md_post_creator_inserimento_post();
   }
   _e('<h3>Generates Posts and Forums</h3>','md_postforum_creator');
   echo '<h3>My Custom Menu Page</h3>';
   echo '<div class="mdpostform container">
            <form action="'.admin_url('admin.php?page=md-postforum-creator-menu-page-slug').'" method="post">
            <div class="descmdpost"><p>';
        _e('Nome Clan','md_postforum_creator');
    echo '</p></div>
            <div class="imputpost"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="'.$_POST['name'].'"></div>
            <div class="clickmdpost"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Invia"></div>
        </form>
    </div>';
};
```

I should add that I noticed some `notices` while testing this, which you should clean up. Enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and you'll see them. I'd do better validation on that `$_POST` data too, if it were me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After your help I managed to have a working version (that I added to my question).
Next step will be to have the possibility to choose if the newly created forum is 'parent' or 'child' of other forums.

Any idea?